# md-autocomplete doesn't show li items text

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, md-autocomplete

I have a md-autocomplete field:

```
<md-autocomplete md-selected-item="videoInfo.lineUp[1]" md-items="item in searchQuery(searchText)" md-search-text="searchText" md-item-text="item.display"></md-autocomplete>
```

I populate `md-items` with

```
$scope.searchQuery = function (searchText) {
    var users = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.users,
        function (value, key) {
            // value = user object
            // key = userId
            var dN = value["display_name"];
            if (dN) {
                var obj = {};
                obj[key] = value;
                obj["display"] = dN;
                if (dN.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
                    users.push(obj);
                }
            }
        });
    return users;
}
```

It working in the sense that I can type in the input field and suggestions are loaded, however the dropdown is empty, i.e. it doesn't show `display_name` as I would have expected. When I select one of the options, the `display_name` of the selected item does show up in the input field. Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define how you display information in the dropdown *within* the `<md-autocomplete>` tag. Here's an example - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/qaOXGJ?editors=1010#0)

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl as vm" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
    <md-autocomplete flex
                 md-selected-item="text"
                 md-no-cache="true"
                 md-items="item in vm.items()"
                 md-min-length="0">
        <span id="autocompleteText" md-highlight-text="searchText">{{item}}</span>
    </md-autocomplete>
</div>
```

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete

Comment: Is there a way to sort the items in the dropdown based on `{{item}}`?

Comment: @SjorsHijgenaar One way would be to use orderBy - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy. It would mean changing your data structure a bit but it should be easy. If by sort you mean filter, then use $filter - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter